# Selecting rows associated with other rows with specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data about phone calls in the form of events which looks something like:

```
|event_id|call_id|event_type      |service|...
|--------|-------|----------------|-------|---
|       1|      1|Call Started    |null   |
|       2|      1|Recorded Message|null   |
|       3|      1|Call at IVR     |null   |
|       4|      1|Agent Ringing   |Sales  |
|       5|      1|Agent Answers   |Sales  |
|       6|      2|Call Started    |null   |
|       7|      2|Recorded Message|null   |
|       8|      2|Call at IVR     |null   |
|       9|      1|Disconnected    |null   |
|      10|      1|Call Ended      |null   |
|      11|      3|Call Started    |null   |
|      12|      3|Recorded Message|null   |
|      13|      2|Agent Ringing   |Support|
|      14|      3|Agent Ringing   |Sales  |
|      15|      2|Agent Answers   |Support|
|      16|      3|Agent Answers   |Sales  |
|      17|      3|Call Hold       |null   |
|      18|      2|Disconnected    |null   |
|      19|      2|Call Ended      |null   |
|      20|      3|Call Retrieved  |Sales  |
|      21|      3|Disconnected    |null   |
|      22|      3|Call Ended      |null   |
```

I want to select only those events that are associated with a call to `Sales`.  As you can see, only certain types of event include data in the `service` column, which is the the column that I need to filter on.  Calls also are not consistent on the number of events they contain due to differences in how they are handled.

I have been filtering the calls in my application by loading all events then using a `GroupBy()` on `call_id` and finally filtering these groups by selecting any that have *any* events with `service` equalling `Sales`.

As in the actual data there is a huge number of calls that I do not want, it would be more efficient to filter this at the database.  How would I do this?

Something like

```
SELECT event_id
FROM events
GROUP BY call_id
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ***this_group*** WHERE service='Sales') > 0
```

The intended output should be

```
|event_id|
|--------|
|       1|
|       2|
|       3|
|       4|
|       5|
|       9|
|      10|
|      11|
|      12|
|      13|
|      16|
|      17|
|      20|
|      21|
|      22|
```

Comment: It's not at all clear how you are arriving at your output or what you are trying to do. Is your output correct? If I understand what you're trying to do, should it not return event 14 rather than 13??

Answer (score 2):

- In a subquery, determine all the unique `call_id` value(s) which has atleast one row containing `service = 'SALES'`.
- Just use this subquery results in the outer query to match `call_id` and get all `event_id` value(s)

**Approach 1**: Use a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)

```
SELECT e1.event_id
FROM events AS e1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e2.call_id
      FROM events AS e2 
      WHERE e2.service = 'SALES') AS dt 
  ON dt.call_id = e1.call_id
```

---

**Approach 2**: Use a `WHERE .. IN(..)`

```
SELECT e2.event_id
FROM events AS e2 
WHERE e2.call_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT e1.call_id
                     FROM events AS e1
                     WHERE e1.service = 'SALES')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT e1.event_id
FROM events e1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM events e2 WHERE e2.call_id = e1.call_id AND e2.service = 'SALES');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think what you are looking for is something like the following. I have used the `WITH` query to single out the calls you're looking for, and a second query to single out events from these calls.

```
WITH salesCalls AS (
  SELECT call_id, event_type, service
  FROM events
  WHERE event_type = "Agent Answers"
  AND service = "Sales"
  GROUP BY call_id, event_type, service
);

SELECT event_id
FROM events
WHERE call_id IN (SELECT call_id FROM salesCalls)
```